# Generate 32 bit depth BMP image in java

Tags: java, image-processing

Have a requirement for any given image need to generate 32 bit depth bmp image in Java.

I googled and looked at Java Advance Image processing and Java2D, but couldnt find exact solution. Appreciate if any responses for the same.

Regards,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use `ImageIO.write(..., "bmp", ...)`? I say about ImageIO because you made an accent on BMP. So, you need a BMP bitmap data with BMP header.

Create BufferedImage (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) with required parameter and serialize it to BMP.

```
...
Robot robot = new Robot();
Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", out);
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I have tried this way but by default it is generating 8 bit depth images. But I am trying to generate 32 bit depth